# Obj C cannot print and transport data even with c file

Tags: ios, objective-c

At the start this is what I input:

```
property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userName;
```

This is the code for outputting the data:

```
void printstructure_1 (void){
    printf("Name:");
    printf("%s," , userName);
}
```

and I want it that such that when I press a button with this code:

```
-(IBAction)Next:(id)sender {
    int printstructure_1 ();
}
```

but after I tested it on the simulator, the data I keyed into the UITextField do not register and display a blank.

Comment: I don't even know how that compiles as the `userName` property is not visible to that C function.  Please post the real code.

Comment: You need to do a considerable amount of studying from basic "C" language through Objective-C and CocoaTouch APIs.

Comment: Without knowing how you hooked up the button to the code it's hard to help. That said there are a lot of issues here. your function returns void, but you assign it to an int. Also userName is the UITextField so you would want the text property of it rather than convert it to a string.'userName.text' is what should work.

Comment: Even if you were using Objective-C's `stringWithFormat`, a UITextField is not a character string.  You at the very least need to reference it's `text` property.  (Basically you don't have the foggiest idea what you're doing, and it shows.)

Comment: @Droppy, the "void..." is in a c file, "property..." is in something.h and "-(IBAction)..." is in .m file.

Comment: @RoyceTeo My comment still stands; that function cannot see that variable.

Comment: Sorry all, I am still quite new to programming. But what other way is there that I do can do to mimic somewhat like that. I linked the button by this:                                        -(IBAction)Next:(id)sender {
    int printstructure_1 ();
} that is about all.

Comment: Objective-C is not a beginner's language.  You should have a good grasp of programming concepts before you begin with it.  You do not appear to appreciate the significance of data types, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is pass the contents of the `UITextField` to the C function, so add a parameter to the function:

cfunctions.h:

```
extern void printstructure_1(const char *userName);
```

cfunctions.c:

```
void printstructure_1(const char *userName){
    printf("Name: %s", userName);
}
```

And then get the current text contents of the `UITextField` in the button action method, converting it to a C-String:

```
#import "cfunctions.h"

-(IBAction)Next:(id)sender {
    printstructure_1([self.userName.text UTF8String]);
}
```